# Plot a time series grouped by id

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I want to plot a time series grouped by id. So that time is my x-value and 'value' is my y-value. How can I plot x and y grouped by 'id' 1?

```
id   time  value 
1    1     0.3
1    2     0.6
1    3     0.9
2    1     0.1
2    2     0.3
2    3     0.6
3    1     0.2
3    2     0.4
3    3     0.5
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you can use [`pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) with [`DataFrame.plot.bar`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.bar.html) or only [`DataFrame.plot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = df.pivot(index='time', columns='id', values='value')
print (df)
id      1    2    3
time               
1     0.3  0.1  0.2
2     0.6  0.3  0.4
3     0.9  0.6  0.5

df.plot.bar()
plt.show()
```

[image: graph]

```
df = df.pivot(index='time', columns='id', values='value')
print (df)
id      1    2    3
time               
1     0.3  0.1  0.2
2     0.6  0.3  0.4
3     0.9  0.6  0.5

df.plot()
plt.show()
```

[image: graph]

Comment: it's more a time series --> df.plot(subplot=True) might be better

Comment: @MMF - Sorry, I dont understand. Can you explain more?

Comment: `I want to plot a time series grouped by id`. I think a subplot with plots from each group might be better than plotting bars to represent a time series. Just about what you're plotting actually.

Comment: Yes, first graph is wrong, I delete it. thank you for comment.

Comment: Alright. Thanks. I what can I do if I only want to plot Id 1 ?

Comment: Then use df.loc[1].plot()

Comment: Or Then use df.loc['1'].plot() if 1 is string value.

Comment: Sorry, I am on phone. But you can before pivot use boolean indexing -`df=df[df.id == '1']`